# fopen returns NULL, but perror prints Success?

Tags: c

Right, I've got this code:

```
if(argc>1){
           FILE * pFile = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
           perror("");
}else{
      FILE * pFile = fopen("hardcoded","rb");
}
if(pFile==NULL){
                puts("Unable to open source file");
                return -1;
}
```

However, I get this weird output:

```
Success
Unable to open source file
```

Weirdlier, if I do this:

```
if(argc>1){
           FILE * pFile = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
           perror("");
}else{
      FILE * pFile = fopen("hardcoded","rb");
}
FILE * pFile = fopen("hardcoded","rb");
if(pFile==NULL){
                puts("Unable to open source file");
                return -1;
}
```

Where hardcoded exists, it all works fine!

What the blazes does that mean?

Compiling with GCC4 on Ubuntu

Comment: dlev already figured out what's wrong with your code.  You didn't show us the entire excerpt, so we had to guess a little.  gcc could have helped you here.  Compile with warnings enabled.  A nice set of options, IMO, is ```gcc -Wall -pedantic```.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt -- yes, those seem to be the minimum practical options

Comment: @Heath: even better is adding to the gcc flags `-std=c89` (or currently equivalent `-ansi`) or `-std=c99` to prevent gnu-isms that are enabled by default (even with -pedantic)

Comment: @pmg: that is a good point.  (Although I prefer the gnuisms to the c99.  If I had my way we could use c89 + declarations in the for-init-statement and C++ comments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm surprised your code compiles, since the you are declaring `FILE *pFile` scoped to the if and the else blocks. If you've declare it prior to that, then remove the `FILE*` text in front of the assignments in the if/else blocks.

Comment: My guess was that `gcc` is adding more features to let someone shoot themselves in the foot even easier.

Comment: +1 OP must have already defined ```FILE *pFile``` at the outer scope, and not shown us that code.  It appears that OP is writing ```FILE *``` every time OP assigns to ```pFile```.

Comment: Huh, didn't know you couldn't declare variables within language constructs. Thanks all :)

Comment: @Hamish Milne:  You can declare variables within language constructs.  That's what you were doing that caused the confusion.  What you should know is that it's possible to hide variables by declaring other variables of the same name, and that this is almost always a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define pFile within the `if` statement, you're losing scope.

```
FILE * pFile;
if(argc>1){
           pFile = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
           perror("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet you've got a `FILE * pfile;` earlier in your code that you didn't include.  If it's outside all blocks, and has static storage duration, it's initialized to NULL.

When you then have `FILE * pfile = fopen(...` in an inner block, the two `pfile`s are two different things.  Therefore, what's happening:

You're defining `pfile` in a block, and opening it fine.  Then you reach the end of the block, and it's being discarded like any other variable local in a block.

You're left with the original `pfile`, which you never opened or assigned anything to, and that's likely to be NULL.

In the second case, you're opening a file and discarding it, and then you have a `FILE * pfile` in the same scope as the testing `if` statement, and that's the one you're testing, so it's fine.

What you need to do is define `pfile` only once, since additional definitions will either cause compiler errors or give you separate versions.  Take all the `FILE *` out of your inner blocks, and just use the same `pfile` all the time.